# terraform Concatenate variable and string

Tags: terraform

I need to pass a variable to a data construct.  However I don't want to build data object with all possible iterations.  The intend is to query AWS to get resource ID.  Here is a sample code:

```
variable "subnet" {}

data "aws_subnet" "subnet" {
  filter {
    name   = "state"
    values = ["available"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["${var.subnet}"]
  }
}

output "data" {
  value = "${data.aws_subnet.'stage-a'.id}"
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output here?

Comment: Mostly I am trying to figure out if it possible to do so.  In the example above I could use aws_vpc but I just want to learn possibilities.
What I would like, in the code above to get back subnet ID from subnet name.

Comment: What do you need to concatenate then? What are you expecting the output to look like?

Answer (score 1):

Your codes nearly work. You use the wrong name with `stage-a` when reference its id in data source `aws_subnet`.

Here is the updated code.

```
variable "subnet" {}

data "aws_subnet" "subnet" {
  filter {
    name   = "state"
    values = ["available"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["${var.subnet}"]
  }
}

output "data" {
  value = "${data.aws_subnet.subnet.id}"
}
```

Since there is no real resource created, you can run `terraform apply` freely.

```
$ TF_VAR_subnet="private" terraform apply
data.aws_subnet.subnet: Refreshing state...

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

data = subnet-21f5a847
```

The only problem is, if there is no match, terraform will report problem and stop to apply the change if required.

```
$ TF_VAR_subnet="not_found" terraform apply
data.aws_subnet.subnet: Refreshing state...

Error: Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:

* data.aws_subnet.subnet: 1 error(s) occurred:

* data.aws_subnet.subnet: data.aws_subnet.subnet: no matching subnet found
```

Comment: This does work, thanks.  However I don't see how I can specify WHICH subnet (in this case) I want.. am I missing something?

Comment: There are three ways to deal with terraform variables. (1) (I have showed you in above sample) via `TF_VAR_subnet`, (2) use the default value directly when set the variable,(3) feed with `-var 'foo=bar'` or `-var-file=foo` with terraform command